# iOS 6+: UITableViewController embedded into Navigation Controller shows table's first section header under status bar when Navigation Bar is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, statusbar, xcode-storyboard

I want my status bar to be drawn over the first section header of UITableView like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLqgO.jpg). (imagine that pink upper dock is the first section header view)

I am developing an application for iOS 6.0+.

The corresponding UITableViewController is the root VC in my navigation hierarchy. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Select the view controller in interface builder, and uncheck the box for "Extend Edges: Under Top Bars"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navcontrolller;
```

In **AppDelegate.m** Call your first class with navigation

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; //allocate window view

     HomeMainVC *Login_page = [[HomeMainVCalloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeMainVC" bundle:nil];
     _navcontrolller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Login_page];
     self.window.rootViewController = _navcontrolller;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

In **HomeMainVC.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

In **HomeMainVC.m** create the table view and other stuff as you want . If you got confused on that too then comment about it.